# python: pyodbc won't connect when I pass user/pass/server values , but connects when I hardcode them

Tags: python, wxpython, connection-string, pyodbc

I am trying to create some GUI for my database application on work. The database is Oracle, and I am using pyodbc and wxPython for my dialogs.
When I try to do this:

```
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=XXX;PWD=YYY;SERVER=ZZZ;")
except:
    print 'Conn failed!'

else:
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

It works. But if I try to assign user/pass/server values to variable, and then do:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=?;PWD=?;SERVER=?;",u_val, p_val, s_val)
```

it fails.
Any ideas why ?

**///SOLVED

Managed to win the connection string. after some meddling I came to solution that works:**

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=" + user_val + ";PWD=" + pass_val + ";SERVER=" + db_val + ";")
```

thanx for help anyway.

Comment: DO NOT put `[solved]` in the title, and don't write the solution into your question If you reached a solution that's not already listed down, [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), you can also accept your own answer to your own question. This other will know that this problem is solved :)

Comment: Why are you refususing to follow the rules of this community?

Comment: Please put that into an answer and accep it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are making assumptions about the values you're passing that aren't valid.

The first step is to print the values out or step through in a debugger and see what they really are.  Make sure there's no extraneous whitespace or newline characters gumming up the works.

It'll bet it will be easy to spot once you have some data.

Comment: I tried to perform strip() but still no result. It's driving me insane.  
If it means anything, I am getting values from wxPython dialog wx.TextCtrl widget, using `str(self.db_user.GetValue()).strip()`.

Comment: Did you look at the values in a debugger?  PyCharm from IntelliJ would make this an easy problem to fix.

Comment: I am at work, and here I have only IDLE (which I like quite much).
and ofc, from home I can not connect to my DB@work.

Comment: Even when I store values into the list and printout the list, value seem to be correct, no whitespaces, no nothing.  
just dumb error. I've tried followin:  
`        except pyodbc.Error,e:
            print e`  
and I get this:  
`function takes at most 1 non-keyword argument`  
and now I am confused bigtime :)

Comment: Does IDLE have a debugger?  Try it tonight.

Comment: it has a debugger, but I am not sure how to use it :)
by the way, I have solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code. I hope it will help you:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}',UID='username',PWD='password',SERVER='servername',u_val, p_val, s_val)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.